# Swapping a WordPress site to a new Domain

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to swap one WordPress site to another domain, Both Domain are hosted on the same server. One site is running WordPress (siteA.com) the second site is not (siteB.com) I wanna swap domains so siteA.com goes to Site B and SiteB.com goes to site A, Can I just swapped the domains around or will I have to do more work because of WordPress only being on one Website?

I have not had much experience with WordPress, But having a look round I have seen a option for Site Address and WordPress Address, do I need to change these?

Comment: Ask the question on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about using Wordpress aren't inherently about programming. This doesn't appear to be about programming.

Comment: Sorry didn't know where to ask this question, just thought someone on here would be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Edit functions.php
If you have access to the site via FTP, then this method will help you quickly get a site back up and running, if you changed those values incorrectly.

1. FTP to the site, and get a copy of the active theme's functions.php file. You're going to edit it in a simple text editor and upload it back to the site.
2. Add these two lines to the file, immediately after the initial "

   update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
   update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );

Use your own URL instead of example.com, obviously.

3. Upload the file back to your site, in the same location. FileZilla offers a handy "edit file" function to do all of the above rapidly; if you can use that, do so.
4. Load the login or admin page a couple of times. The site should come back up.

Important! Do not leave those lines in the functions.php file. Remove them after the site is up and running again.